# python subprocess.call arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, subprocess

on Linux I have the following python source file called visca.py:

```
from subprocess import call
def recall(preset):
    call(["visca-cli", "memory_recall", str(preset)])
```

I open python interpreter in shell and import visca, then i type visca.recall(0) and get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "visca.py", line 13, in recall
    subprocess.call(["visca-cli", "memory_recall", str(preset)])   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 629, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer") TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

However, if I type directly in python shell

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(["visca-cli", "memory_recall", "0"])
10 OK - no return value
0
```

it works. What's the problem?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I did recompile the module and import it after every edit I made to the source file but wasn't aware that the interpreter still had my very first version of the file with incorrect parameters. after I reopened the interpreter, the code was working

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that `bufsize must be an integer`. I am going to guess that whatever value you set for `preset` in the script is not an integer (keep in mind that `0.0` is a float, not an integer). Do a quick check for what your argument is by printing it out in the function.